# Im getting parse error when trying to open my application built by monaca

Tags: monaca

When im trying to build my application i get Parse error: error parsing the project.

It has worked perfect before but not anymore.
Could this be because i recently updated to android 5.0.2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what my issue was. The manifest minsdkversion was updated to 10 so when i changed it to 3 it worked again..

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if your issue is same as mine, but I cannot build any of my 3 projects in Monaca for iOS or Android. 
I'm getting "Build error: Error building project source code"
Two of the 3 projects have not changed since the last successful build so I'm assuming it's a problem with Monaca backend. I've submitted a ticket but they are closed until May 7.